# A better way to simplify with rules than this?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, algebraic-manipulation

```
kappa = {1, (1 - ϕ)*(1 - w[1]) + (1 - ϕ)*w[1] + 
      ϕ*w[1]*(1 - μ[p]) + ϕ*(1 - w[1])*(1 - η[p, 2] - 
        μ[p]), ϕ*w[1]*μ[p] + ϕ*(1 - w[1])*
       (η[p, 2] + μ[p]), (1 - ϕ)*(1 - w[1]) + 
      (1 - ϕ)*w[1] + (1 - ϕ)*ϕ*w[1]*(1 - μ[p]) + 
      ϕ^2*w[1]*(1 - μ[p])^2 + (1 - ϕ)*ϕ*(1 - w[1])*
       (1 - η[p, 2] - μ[p]) + ϕ^2*(1 - w[1])*
       (1 - η[p, 2] - μ[p])^2, ϕ^2*w[1]*(1 - μ[p])*
       μ[p] + ϕ^2*(1 - w[1])*(1 - η[p, 2] - μ[p])*
       (η[p, 2] + μ[p]), (1 - ϕ)*ϕ*w[1]*μ[p] + 
      ϕ^2*w[1]*(1 - μ[p])*μ[p] + (1 - ϕ)*ϕ*(1 - w[1])*
       (η[p, 2] + μ[p]) + ϕ^2*(1 - w[1])*
       (1 - η[p, 2] - μ[p])*(η[p, 2] + μ[p]), 
     ϕ^2*w[1]*μ[p]^2 + ϕ^2*(1 - w[1])*(η[p, 2] + μ[p])^
        2}

rules = {w[1]*μ[p] + (1 - w[1])*(η[p, 2] + μ[p]) -> s[1], 
     w[1]*μ[p]^2 + (1 - w[1])*(η[p, 2] + μ[p])^2 -> s[2]}
```

There is a very simple expression `kappa` I am trying to simplify, using `rules`. I know that a direct replacement `/.` is not going to work as the terms do not match exactly.

So I have looked up some other ways, like `TransformationFunctions`. But I dont understand the examples. How to write out the functions.

The relationships in the `rules` are simple, I can express them like this

```
ss[j_] := w[1] μ[p]^j + (1 - w[1]) (η[p, 2] + μ[p])^j;
ss[1] (* gives s[1] *)
ss[2] (* gives s[2] *)
```

But how to simplify `kappa`, so that i get a term only contains `s[1],s[2],\[Phi]`?

Basically, I am looking for the equivalent command to `simplify/siderels` in Maple, [here](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=simplify%2Fsiderels). At background, it computes a `Gröbner Basis`, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroebnerBasis.html). and then some magic replacement rules applies, it gives me what I want. I don't know much about it, but as long as it can simplify the expression, I am happy.

**Updated (with an answer):**

```
Flatten[GroebnerBasis[Flatten[{Thread[ss[#] - s[#]] & /@ Range[2], #}], {s[1], 
 s[2]}, {w[1], \[Eta][p, 2], \[Mu][p]}] & /@ kappa]
```

After some trial and error, I came up with the above solution. I am not sure how efficient it will be when I have more terms in `kappa` to simplify with more rules.

Is there a better way? Perhaps shorter code?

Comment: `vars = Variables[kappa];
PolynomialReduce[kappa, GroebnerBasis[Subtract @@@ rules, vars], 
  vars][[All, 2]]` will give such a result.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau It does seem much faster and can be extended to a larger dimension of my problem!